# State becomes undefined after dispatch with UseReducer and UseContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-context, use-reducer

Goal: I am trying to toggle the visibility of a 3D model using React reducer and context. 3D rendering is done with React hooks version of a framework called Xeokit. Models are rendered into a canvas element (3DCanvas.js) by giving them as props to a Xeokit Viewer element (XKTModel.js).

The problem is, once a dispatch is sent, the state becomes undefined. The context works only with the default value given to the reducer. Doesn't seem to matter which component sends the dispatch.

I have written into console the state for each component using the UseContext hook to see what is going on. Same thing with the reducer.

I did a lot of searching but could not find a similar issue being addressed. Can someone more experienced spot the mistake I have made?

Context creation:

```
import React from "react";

const ViewControlsContext = React.createContext()

export {ViewControlsContext as default}
```

Reducer:

```
const ViewControlsReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'POPULATE_STATE':
          return action.state, console.log("populate dispatch: ", action, state)
      case 'TOGGLE_SITE_VISIBILITY':
        return {
            ...state,
            //site_visibility: !state.site_visibility
            //^commented out, as will cause an error because state undefined
        }, console.log("toggle dispatch: ", action, state)
      default:
        return state, console.log("default: ", action, state)
    }
  }

  export {ViewControlsReducer as default}
```

App:

```
import React from 'react';

import './App.scss'

import ThreeDeeCanvas from './Components/3DCanvas'

function App(){
  return (<div>
    <ThreeDeeCanvas />
  </div>)
};

export default App;
```

3DCanvas (component into which models are rendered, provides Context):

```
import React, { useEffect, useReducer } from 'react'
import { Container, Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'

import XKTModel from './XKTModel';
import ThreeDeeControls from './3DControls';
import LogoCanvas from './LogoCanvas'
import ViewControlsContext from '../Context/ViewControlsContext';
import ViewControlsReducer from '../Reducers/ViewControlsReducer';

const ThreeDeeCanvas = () => {

    const def = {
        site_visibility: false
    }

    const [viewControls, dispatch] = useReducer(ViewControlsReducer, def)

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch({type: 'POPULATE_STATE', state: def})
        dispatch({type: 'POPULATE_STATE', state: def}) //test, with this state is undefined
    }, [])
    
    console.log("3dcanvas: ", viewControls)

    return (
        <div>
            <LogoCanvas/>
            <Col className='ThreeDeeWindow'>
            <ViewControlsContext.Provider value={{viewControls, dispatch}} >
                <XKTModel/>
                <ThreeDeeControls/>
            </ViewControlsContext.Provider>
            </Col>
        </div>
    )
}

export {ThreeDeeCanvas as default}
```

XKTModel (source and props for 3D models, uses Context):

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { navCubeSettings } from '../models';
import { XKTViewer } from 'xeokit-react';

import ViewControlsContext from '../Context/ViewControlsContext';
import { IFCObjectDefaultColors } from '../default_colors';

const mainModel = {
  id: 'main_model',
  src: './xkt/Showcase.xkt',
  metaModelSrc: './xkt/Showcase.json',
  edges: true,
  objectDefaults: IFCObjectDefaultColors,
}

const siteModel = {
  id: 'site_model',
  src: './xkt/ShowcaseSite.xkt',
  metaModelSrc: './xkt/ShowcaseSite.json',
  edges: true
}

const XKTModel = () => {

  const {viewControls} = useContext(ViewControlsContext)
  console.log("XKTModel: ", viewControls)

  //siteModel.visible = viewControls.site_visibility
  //^commented out, as will cause an error because state undefined
  
 
  return (
    <XKTViewer
    canvasID="modelCanvas"
    width={800}
    height={800}
    models={[mainModel, siteModel]}
    navCubeSettings={navCubeSettings}
    />
  ) 
};

export default XKTModel;
```

3DControls (Container for individual 3D controls):

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { Container, Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'

import ThreeDeeControl from './3DControl'
import ViewControlsContext from '../Context/ViewControlsContext'

const ThreeDeeControls = () => {

    const {viewControls} = useContext(ViewControlsContext)
    
    console.log("3dcontrols: ", viewControls)

    return (
        <Container className='ThreeDeeControls p-0 d-flex justify-content-between'>
            <ThreeDeeControl id='site' label='Show site'/>
        </Container>
    )
}

export {ThreeDeeControls as default}
```

3DControl (individual toggles for changing 3D view props, sends dispatch):

```
import React, {  useState, useContext, useReducer } from 'react'
import { Container, Form } from 'react-bootstrap'

import ViewControlsContext from '../Context/ViewControlsContext'


const ThreeDeeControl = ({id, label}) => {

    const {viewControls, dispatch} = useContext(ViewControlsContext)

    console.log("3dsinglecontrol: ", viewControls)

    const [isSwitchOn, setIsSwitchOn] = useState(false);

    const onSwitchAction = () => {
    setIsSwitchOn(!isSwitchOn);
    dispatch({type: 'TOGGLE_SITE_VISIBILITY'})
    }

    return (
            <Form className='ThreeDeeControl'>
                <Form.Check  
                    type="switch"
                    id={id}
                    label={label}
                    checked={isSwitchOn}
                    onChange={onSwitchAction}
                />
            </Form>
    )
}

export {ThreeDeeControl as default}
```

Comment: Comma operator returns the last value. If you have return foo, console.log, it returns undefined as console.log returns undefined in your reducer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the result of the comma operator, i.e. the result of `console.log` which is a void return.

[Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

> The **comma operator** (`,`) evaluates each of its operands (from left
> to right) and ***returns the value of the last operand***. This lets
> you create a compound expression in which multiple expressions are
> evaluated, with the compound expression's final value being the value
> of the rightmost of its member expressions.

## Solution

Log the state and action independent of the reducer function return.

```
const ViewControlsReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'POPULATE_STATE':
      console.log("populate dispatch: ", { action, state });
      return action.state;

    case 'TOGGLE_SITE_VISIBILITY':
      console.log("toggle dispatch: ", { action, state });
      return {
        ...state,
        site_visibility: !state.site_visibility
      };

    default:
      console.log("default: ", { action, state });
      return state;
  }
}
```